# integral in the sense of distributions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, distribution-theory

need help for this situation :
I have a function real values function $f$ and I have tu study this object :
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} t \; \mathrm{d}f(t)$$
My function $f$ is decreasing, left-continuous and have a finite number of "jumps".
"in the sense of distributions". I don't understand the meaning of "in the sense of distributions".

Comment: The derivative at each jump location will have a Dirac mass times the magnitude of the jump. In the "sense of distributions" is the go-to phrase when you have to use the language and machinery of distributions directly in your work (integration by parts, etc).

Comment: you need to give some meaning to the symbol $df$, I dont know one. However using the right-continuous version of $f$ you have a meaning for $df$, just take a look a "Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure" somewhere

Comment: Thanks for answers !